# Common Lisp - SLIME in infinte loop

Tags: lisp, infinite-loop, fibonacci, do-loops

I have started to learn Common Lisp a few days ago reading the book from [Peter Seibel](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/). I have downloaded the lispbox-0.7 for Windows and tried out some of the concepts in the SLIME REPL.

Now I'm at chapter 7. Macros and Standard Control Structures / Loops and I found this intressting `do` expression for the 11th Fibonacci number

```
(do ((n 0 (1+ n))
 (cur 0 next)
 (next 1 (+ cur next)))
((= 10 n) cur))
```

I defined following function

```
(defun fib (n) (do ((i 1 (1+ i)) (cur 0 next) (next 1 (+ cur next))) ((= n i) cur)))
```

The function does what I expected and returns the nth Fibonacci number. Now for curiosity i tried summing the first 10 fibonacci numbers using a dotimes loop

```
(let ((sum 0)) (dotimes (k 10) (setf sum (+ sum (fib k)))) sum)
```

But this expression runs indefinitly and i don't understand why. Maybe here is another concept I don't know. I tried a simpler example like

```
(dotimes (k 10) (fib k))
```

which should return `NIL`. But this also runs indefinitly. Can someone explain to me what I am missing?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, was not carefull enougth. the code tries to evaluate fib 0, but the test condition in `do` cannot be fulfilled. Thats why it runs indefinitly

fixing it by `(fib (+ k 1))`

Comment: Either you make sure fib is never called with input zero (hard), or you make fib robust to invalid input. You could have an auxiliary recursive function fib% that doesn't check inputs and call it from a safe fib function that calls check-type